# 'ValidationError' is not convertible to 'Error';did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Tags: ios, swift, validation, compiler-errors, xcode8

Hello I'm new to Swift development. I'm developing a code for user input field validation. I've imported [Validator](https://github.com/adamwaite/Validator) and *`SwiftValidator`* libraries. I couldn't get rid of this error. I followed the updated syntax too but still the error persists.

Here is the code:

```
func addFieldValidation()  {

        var emailRules = ValidationRuleSet<String>()
        emailRules.add(rule: ValidationRulePattern(pattern: .EmailAddress, error: ValidationError(textField:emailTextField, error: "Enter valid email address"))) //****<---Getting error here******


        emailTextField.validationRules=emailRules;

        emailTextField.validateOnInputChange(enabled:  true);

        emailTextField.validationHandler = { result in
            switch result {
            case .valid:
                self.enableSignUp(true)
            case .invalid(let failureErrors):
                let messages = failureErrors.map { $0.message }//****<---Getting error here as "Value of type 'Error' has no member 'message' "******
                print(messages)
                self.enableSignUp(false)
            }
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to validate email address is valid or not?

Comment: Yes.using Validator..It's a legacy code  developed a year back.Now I'm updating the changes.   @Alwin

Answer (score 0):

I have a different way of email validation

```
// email validation method
    func isValidEmail(emailAddress:String) -> Bool {
        // print("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: emailAddress)
    }
```

Comment: I want to validate using Validator or SwiftValidator. I'm familiar with the snippet you 've sent. Thanks for the quick response Alwin. Expecting solution with similar snippet I posted. :)